# How to remove the common words from two strings, while keeping the white-space intact using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have two strings,

```
def str1 = "This is test"
def str2 = "That is test"
```

I want to find the difference between these two strings using Groovy.

I have tried the `-`operator but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
println 'This is test' - 'That is test'
```

I want the output to be `This That`

But, the above code evaluates to the first string `This is test`. Where am I going wrong? Is there any other way to get the difference between two strings using Groovy?

Comment: Could you please state, what kind of result you expect?  Do you want a full diff, the difference after the first initial common part, the set of chars from the first string, that are not in the second?

Comment: I want the result to be `C D EF`.

Comment: Why do you want `C` and `D` both and/or that second `AB` not?

Comment: I just want to remove the common characters from both the strings but the spaces to be intact. Since `AB` is common in both the strings I want them gone, resulting in `C D EF`

Comment: I have edited the question to explain what I exactly want.

Comment: Yes, me to and things clashed...  You now only want whole words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minus operator for String works differently - it removes part of String. In your case you get `This is test` as a result because this String does not contain a substring like `That is test`.

If you want to get a concatenation of words that are different in both strings you can tokenize both strings and transpose them to a pairs of words and remove pairs that contain the same words. Remaining words can be joined with space character, something like:

```
def str1 = "This is test"
def str2 = "That is test"

def diff = [str1.tokenize(), str2.tokenize()].transpose() // creates a list of pairs like [["This", "That"], ["is", "is"], ["test", "test"]]
        .findAll { it[0] != it[1] }                       // filters out pairs containing the same word
        .flatten()                                        // flats [["This", "That"]] to ["This", "That"]
        .join(' ')                                        // creates a final String "This That"

assert diff == 'This That'
```

Comment: it returns CAB. That is not that desired output. I have edited my question to explain what I want. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: @ANIL Thanks for clearing things up. I have updated the answer to returns expected value.

Comment: Thank you so much @Szymon Stepniak.